# Filtering duplicates form array of objects

Tags: javascript, foreach, distinct-values

looking for an explanation as to why the below code doesn't filter correctly. I have an array of objects, one of those properties is buy_mth_yr which is in the format mmm-yy as below.

```
buy_mth_yr : 'Apr-18'
```

I am trying to get a list of all unique buy_mth_yr values and return as a list of label-value objects, to be passed into a filter. I have already found a solution in a separate stack overflow question, the point of me asking this question is more to understand why my original solution below doesn't work. so lets say `data` is my list of objects with the buy_mth_yr key. the if statement calls every time and I end up with an unfiltered list. any help/insight appreciated!

```
let distinct = [];
    data.forEach(record =>{
        let temp = {label: record.buy_mth_yr, value: record.buy_mth_yr}
        if(!(temp in distinct)){
            distinct.push(temp)
        }
    })   
    return distinct;
```

Comment: Did you ty stepping through and/or using `console.log` to see what the result of `if(!(temp in distinct))` is? I mean what is the question here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> to understand why my original solution below doesn't work

Because you are doing a referential comparison - first link that popped up on google, it might help: https://dmitripavlutin.com/how-to-compare-objects-in-javascript/#1-referential-equality

```
({a:1}) !== ({a:1})

// but
const obj = {a:1};
obj === obj
```

`temp` will **never** be in `distinct` because it is always a new object, every time.

EDIT:

To add to this, a better solution (and there's a thousand ways to write this, below is but one example) would look like this:

```
const isShallowEqualWith = (a) => (b) => {
  const keysA = Object.keys(a);
  const keysB = Object.keys(b);
  return keysA.length === keysB.length && keysA.every(k => a[k] === b[k]);
}

let distinct = [];
    data.forEach(record =>{
        let temp = {label: record.buy_mth_yr, value: record.buy_mth_yr}
        if(!distinct.find(isShallowEqualWith(temp)) {
          distinct.push(temp);
        }
    })   
    return distinct;
```

Comment: thanks, had a feeling it was something along those lines!

Answer (score -1):

I think your `!(temp in distinct)` is not the check you want to do : use `!distinct.includes(temp)` instead.

However you should take a look to lodash library with `_.uniq` and `_.uniqBy` functions : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/lodash-_-uniqby-method/